# Implementing a Wordpress custom function

Tags: php, wordpress

Site I’m working on is a radio show. I have a bunch of custom fields, courtesy of Advanced Custom Fields, for links to musicians’ websites, social profiles, etc.. For the last few years, we’ve used a Genesis child theme to display them, and [the code I adapted](http://jeffcohan.com/advanced-custom-fields-genesis/) worked great. The radio show’s host/producer now wants to move to a non-Genesis theme, and I’m having some trouble making it work.

[Here’s an example](http://www.earthsongs.net/annie-humphrey/) from the site we’re migrating FROM, which includes the functioning code. (The Artist Links box, floated to the right of the main copy.)

[Here’s the same post at the new site](http://indigefi-live.nativeftp.org/annie-humphrey/), where the code doesn’t yet display. (It will display in the same place.) FWIW, the theme is [GrandBlog](http://themes.themegoods.com/grandblog/demo/).

Here’s the code:

```
 <?php

 add_action ('if_artist_links');

 function if_artist_links() {

// These are the custom field keys defined in the dashboard:
$metas_links = array(
    'website',
    'album', 
    'tour', 
    'twitter', 
    'facebook',
    'bandcamp',
    'soundcloud',
    'youtube',
    'instagram',
    'linkedin',
    'myspace',
    'image',
);

// If _any_ ACF field is filled in, it's a go.
$has_meta = false; // init
foreach ($metas_links as $test ) {
    if ( get_field($test) ) {
        $has_meta = true;
        continue; // Just need one meta field filled to create the div.
    }
}
if ( $has_meta ) {
    echo '<div class="custom-data artist-links">';
    echo '<h2 class="artistname">' ?> <?php the_field('name') ?></h2>
    <center><strong> <?php the_field('tribe') ?></strong></center> <?php
    foreach ( $metas_links as $meta_links ) {
        $$meta_links = get_field($meta_links);
        if ( $$meta_links ) {
            $f_object = get_field_object($meta_links);
            $label = $f_object['label'];
            echo '<div class="' . $meta_links . '">' .
            '<a href="'. $$meta_links .'" target="blank"><span class="label">' . $label . '</a></span>' . 
            '</div>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div><!-- /.custom-data -->';
}
}

?>`
```

Where there’s an ACF value, a link is created. Where there’s no ACF value, there’s no link. Just one link is required to make the box appear.

As far as I can tell, I’m not telling the code to run, or run in the right way. If you can help me do that, I’ll sing your praises through the weekend.

If possible, I’d really like to wrap this up in a WP plugin, for simplicity and ease of maintenance, and to put minimal code in single.php.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use WordPress `the_content` hook. Replace this in your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function single_add_to_content( $content ) {    
    if( is_single() ) {        
        // These are the custom field keys defined in the dashboard:
        $metas_links = array(
            'website',
            'album', 
            'tour', 
            'twitter', 
            'facebook',
            'bandcamp',
            'soundcloud',
            'youtube',
            'instagram',
            'linkedin',
            'myspace',
            'image',
        );

        // If _any_ ACF field is filled in, it's a go.
        $has_meta = false; // init
        foreach ($metas_links as $test ) {
            if ( get_field($test) ) {
                $has_meta = true;
                continue; // Just need one meta field filled to create the div.
            }
        }
        if ( $has_meta ) {
            $content.= '<div class="custom-data artist-links">';
            $content.= '<h2 class="artistname">'.get_field('name').'</h2>
            <center><strong>'.get_field('tribe').'</strong></center>';
            foreach ( $metas_links as $meta_links ) {
                $$meta_links = get_field($meta_links);
                if ( $$meta_links ) {
                    $f_object = get_field_object($meta_links);
                    $label = $f_object['label'];
                    $content.= '<div class="' . $meta_links . '">' .
                    '<a href="'. $$meta_links .'" target="blank"><span class="label">' . $label . '</a></span>' . 
                    '</div>';
                }
            }
            $content.= '</div><!-- /.custom-data -->';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'single_add_to_content' );
```

Or you can copy 'single.php' to your child theme and add this code directly without function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! When I drop this into functions.php, I get the following: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: `Call to undefined function get_the_field() in /home2/nativeft/public_html/indigefi-live/wp-content/themes/grandblog/functions.php:1598 Stack trace: #0 /home2/nativeft/public_html/indigefi-live/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): single_add_to_content('<p>Ojibwe artis...') #1 /home2/nativeft/public_html/indigefi-live/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<p>Ojibwe artis...', Array)…` it goes on from there to name five more.

Comment: Sorry, `get_the_field()` should be `get_field()`, please check the updated answer.

Comment: One more question: I'd like to add it before the_content. I've googled around and don't see a copy/paste way to do that. Is there a simple way to tell it to place my function before the_content starts? Thanks so much again.

Comment: Change all `$content.=` occurrences to `$newcontent.=` and change 'return' statement to `return $newcontent.$content;`. That's it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your time. Unfortunately, that makes an infinite box-within-a-box.  See here: http://indigefi-live.nativeftp.org/annie-humphrey/

Comment: It shouldn't, I didn't see any infinite boxes in the link above, can you update your new code in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was mucking with it and made a bit of a mess. I'll have it ready to show you in 5-10.

Comment: I must have done something wrong the first time. I started fresh, copied everything, copied your edits, and it works. IT WORKS. Thank you so much. You are the kindest person on the Internet today.